# Solana Token Extensions to Modify Transaction

Tags: spl-token, cpi, instructions, token-extensions

Regarding token extensions: https://cdn.builder.io/o/assets%2Fce0c7323a97a4d91bd0baa7490ec9139%2F83c26b9268f64400b8eb67442579a31a?alt=media&token=525415b0-d3ea-48d7-83d6-0fb0d9e522c6

"Transfer hook: Allows calling specific programs with each
token transfer."

Is this referring to CPIs that could append instructions to the transaction before submission? Or saying it's a callback to a submitted transaction that touched the token? I'd like to insert instructions to a transaction that interacts with my token.

Answer (score 0):

The transfer hook program is called during `transfer` directly, so there's no instructions added to the transaction. Instead, the transfer hook includes the additional accounts required to CPI into the transfer hook program, and the token program constructs the appropriate instruction.

In general, there's no way to enforce that certain instructions are added in a transaction from the client side, since anyone can construct transactions however they want.

If you can design your solution to work as a transfer hook, then it can be done automatically by the token program (assuming the accounts are provided).